# Python3 regex not match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use re.findall to match a string, but it doesn't match anything:

```
>>> str = ''' description TESTE ONE Gi0/0/0\n ip vrf forwarding test\n ip address       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n ip flow monitor fnf input\n ip flow monitor fnf output\n negotiation    auto\n cdp enable\n'''
>>> print(str)
     description TESTE ONE Gi0/0/0
     ip vrf forwarding test
     ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
     ip flow monitor fnf input
     ip flow monitor fnf output
     negotiation auto
     cdp enable
     >>> desc = re.findall(r'^ description (.*)$', str)
     >>> desc
         []"
```

In regex101.com, the same regex works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by ApproachingDarknessFish is correct if you are attempting to match the *entire* input string that follows ' description ' as provided. However, you are doing a `findall`, which strongly suggests that you are looking for multiple occurrences of `^ description (.*)$` and you therefore mean for the anchors `^` and `$` to represent the start and end of *lines* rather than the start and end of the entire string. If that is the case, then you do *not* want to use the `re.DOTALL` flag but rather the `re.M` flag:

```
import re

str = ''' description TESTE ONE Gi0/0/0
 ip vrf forwarding test
 ip address       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 ip flow monitor fnf input 
 ip flow monitor fnf output
 negotiation    auto
 cdp enable
 description another one thrown in for good measure!
'''
print(re.findall(r'^ description (.*)$', str, re.M))
```

Prints:

```
['TESTE ONE Gi0/0/0', 'another one thrown in for good measure!']
```

Comment: Booboo, thanks for this advice. In my case I don't have new lines with 'description' only one,  and re.M stop on new line(/n), so works very well for me.

Comment: To be precise, as long as you do not specify `re.DOTALL`, the `.` character will never match the newline. So if you do not care where on a line ' description ' is, you can get away with just `re.findall(r' description (.*)', str))` or even `re.search(r' description (.*)', str)[1]` if you are only expecting one match knowing that `(.*)` will only match characters until it gets to a newline character. **But keep the regex as is if ` description ` *must* be at the start of a line.**

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy is caused by the behavior of the dot (`.`) character. In [Python's regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `.` does not match newlines by default, hence the line breaks in your strings cause the `(.*)` group to not match.

The behavior or `.` can be changed by passing the `re.DOTALL` flag to the method:

```
re.findall(r'^ description (.*)$', str, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: The problem of re.DOTALL is that all other lines match too        >>> print(re.findall(r'^ description (.*)$', str, re.DOTALL))
['TESTE ONE Gi0/0/0\n ip vrf forwarding test\n ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n ip flow monitor fnf input\n ip flow monitor fnf output\n negotiation auto\n cdp enable\n']
>>>